# Is there a way to save a users data during an iPhone app update?

Tags: iphone, ios

The users information is stored in a directory inside the apps documents directory. I dont know if I should be trying to copy the documents directory for the old version to the new version or if the update will automatically do this. Or is there another way altogether?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files inside Documents directory are preserved during an app update.

Comment: Okay, thank you. That was probably in the documentation somewhere but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Apple documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4094